# Invoke .NET static class methods from Powershell script

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Trying to use a .NET DLL from a Powershell script. The purpose of the DLL is logging. I am able to execute the commands without errors, but no log shows up. The class contains `try/catch` blocks that may be failing silently.

Here is my Powershell code:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\path\to\dll.dll"
[NS.MsgLog]::GetLogPath("C:\path\to\log.log")
[NS.MsgLog]::LogMessage([NS.MsgLevel]::Info, "line1")
```

`GetPath()` sets a local path variable 
`LogMessage()` does the logging work

Here is the basic .NET code:

```
namespace NS
{
    public enum MsgLevel
    {
        Info,

        ...more code here

    public static class MsgLog
    {

      public static void LogMessage(MsgLevel level, string Message, params object[] Args)
      {
          try
          {
              // Open file.
              // Ensure directory path exist.
              if (!File.Exists(MsgLog.LogPath))
              {
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(MsgLog.LogPath));
              }

              ...more code follows

      public static void GetLogPath(string Path)
      {
          LogPath = Path;
      }

      ...more code follows
```

I can confirm that the DLL exists without errors like so

```
PS Z:\> add-type -Path "C:\path\to\dll.dll"
PS Z:\> [NS.MsgLog]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MsgLog                                   System.Object


PS Z:\> [NS.MsgLevel]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     MsgLevel                                 System.Enum
```

`LogMessage()` works fine everywhere else, so I don't think there's any bugs in the function -- but there could be bugs in the way I am invoking the function.

**UPDATE**

Here's verification the function exists:

```
PS Z:\> [NS.MsgLog] | Get-Member -Static

TypeName: NS.MsgLog

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
GetLogPath      Method     static void GetLogPath(string Path)
LogBOJ          Method     static void LogBOJ(), static void LogBOJ(string AppName)
LogEOJ          Method     static void LogEOJ(), static void LogEOJ(string AppName)
LogMessage      Method     static void LogMessage(NS.MsgLevel level, string Message, Params System.Object[] Args)
ReferenceEquals Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
```

Comment: If you're using a static class, you should be able to access its members.  Try `[ClassName] | Get-Member -Static` to make sure what you're calling exists, then try accessing the members that should be changed to confirm they are set.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 check the **UPDATE** added

Comment: Why does your getter set a path?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 (not my code)

Comment: I'd fix it and create a real getter/setter or make the log path public.

Comment: did you try setting breakpoints inside your code and see what is happening?

Comment: @pm100 I'm not sure how I could go about debugging a DLL that is loaded from a Powershell script

Comment: in visual studio choose debug->Attach to process and select the powershell process of the ps shell you are running in (echo $PID to get is pid). Or put Debugger.Launch in your c# library

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and it worked for me. I could get the log with exact Powershell commands you provided. I think there is something wrong in `LogMessage`. You could remove `try/catch` block and give it another shot. It might be throwing exceptions.

Comment: Removed try catch statements, but no luck. It's like the function invocation is an empty call. The very first line of code is to create the log file, but the log file is never created. Plus, I'm not receiving any errors when I execute the function call from Powershell